Will creating and stopping a SignalR connection for each request fix the need for a sticky session?
I was reading about how you need sticky sessions enabled if using SignalR in a server farm.  We can't do that in our situation so I wondered if I instead simply created and stopped the connection in the method that connects and gets data from the server, if that would negate the need for sticky sessions?
And, also, in a set up like the below code, will that release the resources as expected from the client and server for the connection so that it's only alive for as long as it's needed to complete the operation?  The main idea with this code is using SignalR to call a hub method that calls an AI and streams the response back.
function getChatResponse(question){
    const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl("/chatHub")
        .withAutomaticReconnect()
        .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
        .build();

    await connection.start();

    let chatData = { Question: question, PreviousQuestions: chatHistory };
    
    connection.stream("Chat", chatData)
        .subscribe({
            next: (item) => {
                if (item !== null)
                {
                    aiAnswer += item;
                    document.getElementById(selectors.aiResponseDiv).innerHTML += item.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
                }
            },
            complete: () => {
                chatHistory.push({
                    Message: question,
                    EventDate: new Date(),
                    Role: 0
                });
                chatHistory.push({
                    Message: aiAnswer,
                    EventDate: new Date(),
                    Role: 1
                });
                connection.stop().then(() => {
                        console.log("connection closed");
                    }
                );
            },
            error: (err) => {
                toastr.error(err);
            },
        });
}


Creating and stopping a SignalR connection for each request, as shown in your code, effectively avoids the need for sticky sessions in a server farm setup. By establishing a new, short-lived connection for each operation, you ensure that each request is independent, thus eliminating issues related to session state across different servers. This approach also ensures that resources are properly released on both the client and server after each request. However, be aware of the potential performance overhead introduced by repeatedly creating and tearing down connections.

Thanks.  Where we'll be using it won't be seeing a lot of use but I am interested in what kind of overhead would be introduced if you can give a little more info on that.
